# How does CloudFlare's 'purge' feature work?

Tags: .htaccess, cdn, cloudflare, cache-expiration

I've adjusted the expiration tags on many of the files of my website (with .htaccess). As you know, this can create a tiny problem of a users browser not showing the most updated version of a website until the cached version of the file expires.

I began looking for a way to avoid this and then I remembered using CloudFlare some time ago. CloudFlare makes it possible to adjust these same tags but it also has a purge feature. What is 'purge' doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purge is telling us to [purge the files](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache-) that CloudFlare has cached on your site. You can do for the whole site (purge cache) or purge by single file.

Comment: I see. So when a user views a webpage of a website that's using CloudFlare, the user is viewing the cached version that CloudFlare has.